# Random TLS/SSL errors

Tags: ssl, tls1.2

I get random errors when using TLS 1.1 & 1.2 on Ubuntu 16.04. Errors occur using browsers (Chrome and Firefox) and wget, etc. Secure connections sometimes work, but most of the time they don't. Here is an example with wget by forcing TLS 1.2:

```
baris@computer:~$ wget --secure-protocol=TLSv1_2 https://github.com/tiny-dnn/tiny-dnn/archive/v1.0.0a3.tar.gz
--2018-01-25 17:16:46--  https://github.com/tiny-dnn/tiny-dnn/archive/v1.0.0a3.tar.gz
Resolving github.com (github.com)... 192.30.253.113, 192.30.253.112
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|192.30.253.113|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://codeload.github.com/tiny-dnn/tiny-dnn/tar.gz/v1.0.0a3 [following]
--2018-01-25 17:16:46--  https://codeload.github.com/tiny-dnn/tiny-dnn/tar.gz/v1.0.0a3
Resolving codeload.github.com (codeload.github.com)... 192.30.253.121, 192.30.253.120
Connecting to codeload.github.com (codeload.github.com)|192.30.253.121|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 12885646 (12M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘v1.0.0a3.tar.gz.17’

v1.0.0a3.tar.gz.17            65%[=============================>                 ]   7.99M  37.9MB/s    in 0.2s    

2018-01-25 17:16:46 (37.9 MB/s) - Read error at byte 8381776/12885646 (error:1408F119:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:decryption failed or bad record mac). Retrying.

--2018-01-25 17:16:47--  (try: 2)  https://codeload.github.com/tiny-dnn/tiny-dnn/tar.gz/v1.0.0a3
Connecting to codeload.github.com (codeload.github.com)|192.30.253.121|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 12885646 (12M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘v1.0.0a3.tar.gz.17’

v1.0.0a3.tar.gz.17           100%[==============================================>]  12.29M  50.7MB/s    in 0.2s    

2018-01-25 17:16:48 (50.7 MB/s) - ‘v1.0.0a3.tar.gz.17’ saved [12885646/12885646]
```

Here is another example extracted from a CMake download log file:

```
# Connected to raw.githubusercontent.com (151.101.116.133) port 443 (#0)
# ALPN, offering http/1.1
# Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
# successfully set certificate verify locations:
#   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
#   CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
# TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS header, Certificate Status (22):
# [5 bytes data]
# TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
# [512 bytes data]
# [5 bytes data]
# TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
# [108 bytes data]
# [5 bytes data]
# TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
# [3182 bytes data]
# [5 bytes data]
# TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
# [333 bytes data]
# [5 bytes data]
# TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
# [4 bytes data]
# [5 bytes data]
# TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
# [70 bytes data]
# [5 bytes data]
# TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
# [1 bytes data]
# [5 bytes data]
# TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
# [16 bytes data]
# [5 bytes data]
# TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS alert, Server hello (2):
# [2 bytes data]
# error:140943FC:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad record mac
# Closing connection 0
#
```

What might be causing this?

**Edit:** It turns out there was a problem with the CPU (i7-7700K). Running the CRC test suite from Intel (https://github.com/intel/soft-crc), I realized that the CRCs fail on core #0, but they run fine on the remaining cores. Similarly firefox or chrome run fine on cores #1,#2,#3 using the taskset utility.

**Edit 2:** Interestingly the problem disappeared after removing the CPU and installing it back in. All cores are working fine now. Perhaps one of the pins did not have a good contact. First time I see such a problem that affects only a certain type of calculation on a CPU.

Comment: Network issues. Try capturing network traffic with Wireshark or tcpdump while reproducing the issue.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz Thanks for the suggestions. It seems to be hardware problem --see my edit.

Comment: @LuisMuñoz One final edit, hopefully: After reinstalling the CPU, the problem is fixed. All cores are able to complete the CRC test. No more problems with https pages.

Comment: Weird case, indeed.